# can i send form-data with axios with delete request in react?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

i need send this request with axios.

[image]

i need header as multipart request, like below

```
  headers: {
        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
```

I used spring boot for backend. It expect maltipart not application/json. I tried below code, But it not worked for multipart.

```
axios.delete(URL, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: authorizationToken
  },
  data: {
    source: source
  }
});
```

Comment: You can generate the axios code for this inside postman. Try the `code` section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @Sinan Yaman. I generated it using POSTMAN. Answer is

```
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var data = new FormData();
data.append('keyName', 'project/photoes/1613388881570-note1.txt');

var config = {
  method: 'delete',
  url: 'localhost:8080/storage/deleteFile',
  headers: { 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Typically before make frontend we test our backend with postman. For any type of frontend *http calls code* can automatically generate using postman. This is awesome feature of **POSTMAN**. Follow below steps.

1. Press the *code* button
   [image: image 1]
2. Select the your backend code environment
   [image: image 2]